# How could I set up a 'nice' Capistrano deployment?

Tags: capistrano, nice

How could I setup a nice indice on `cap:deploy`?

I want the remote server to nice the `cp` commands like so:

```
nice -n 19 cp ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about **cp**. Don't you use an SCM?

I tried with my setup (I use subversion) and this seems to work. In *deploy.rb*, add:

```
set :scm_command, "nice -19 svn"
```

It seems somewhat more difficult if you don't use an SCM, you'll have to overload checkout() in *deploy/scm/none.rb*.

Answer (score 0):

For those who wants to nice `assets:precomile` task, the very time consuming task, following worked for me.

```
namespace :deploy do
  task :map_bins_to_nice  do
    SSHKit.config.command_map.prefix[:rake]&.unshift('nice -n 19')
  end
end

Capistrano::DSL.stages.each do |stage|
  after stage, 'deploy:map_bins_to_nice'
end
```

Note that this makes every `rake` task to be niced.  E.g. `rake db:migrate`.

This was originally taken from following post (Japanese).  http://d.hatena.ne.jp/nekonokataomoi/20140819/1408443332